# Add window to Activity created by Titanium Module

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I made a Activity using Titanium Mobile Module, and it has simple white background.

Can I pass a window (Titanium object) from this Activity to another js files to add (draw) new objects (like buttons) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

If you are using *Alloy* for it, just do anything similar as

```
//index.js
function doClick(e) {
    require('utils').createButton($.index);
}
```

And

```
//utils.js inside /lib
exports.createButton = function createButton(window){
     var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
          height:'20dp',
          width:'20dp',
          title:'Test'
     });
     window.add(button);
 }
```

However, keep in mind, to your memory consumption, because you are sending a big object `$.index` as a local variable.